# simple present vs. present participle on context

Tags: tense

An user issued a bug on [meta.stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394157/12990675) recently. After that another guy (engineer) made some fix and then said

> This **should be** resolved.

I guess that sentence should be

> This **should have been** resolved.

Since the engineer was trying to convey the fact of job done.

Is my understanding right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"This should be resolved." probably means that he thinks the fix he just made has resolved the problem. You also might use the same words to say that you think the problem needs to be resolved but it isn't yet.

Your suggested substitution would only be used with an expression of time, for example, "This should have been resolved by now" or "... a long time ago." That would express dissatisfaction that it isn't yet resolved, or that it wasn't resolved earlier.

Comment: I guess another expression might has less ambiguity, which is, "the fix (fix_id) should resolved this issue", right?

Comment: As you have put it now, it is not grammatical. It should be "The fix should have resolved this issue", but that is still ambiguous in the way I pointed out in my answer. An unambiguous statement would be "This fix has resolved the issue.", To say it with less assurance, one could say "I think this fix has resolved the issue."